# pandas 0.10.1 to 0.11.0 .ix method

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge dataframe with unique index.  This was working code in pandas 0.10.1 but seems to break in pandas 0.11.0.

Simplistically I have a DataFrame (df) with 2 columns:  "Classification' and 'A', Both populated with data.  The df is uniquely indexed.  I want to overwrite the value in A if the 'Classification is not in a certain list.

```
# df contains the original data
accurate_list = ['corr1', 'corr2', 'corr3']
# x is filtered dataframe with only inaccurate entries
x = df[~df.Classification.isin(accurate_list)]
df.ix[x.index,'A'] = df['Classification']
```

Sorry could not figure out how to get some sample data in here.   The problem seems to be in the last line with the .ix method.   Quoting from the pandas 0.11.0 whats new documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#v0-11-0-april-22-2013:

> ".ix supports mixed integer and label based access. It is primarily label based, but will fallback to integer positional access. .ix is the most general and will support any of the inputs to .loc and .iloc, as well as support for floating point label schemes. .ix is especially useful when dealing with mixed positional and label based hierarchial indexes."

No exception messages... It seems that the data loses alignment though.

Any ideas if this is a pandas bug or if I wrote bad code in pandas 0.10.1?

Here is some sample code.  That illustrate the problem:

```
accurate_ICB = ['SA EQUITY CFD', 'SA EQUITY', 'SA SSF']
print pd.__version__
data = {'Classification': ['SA EQUITY CFD', 'bbb', 'SA EQUITY', 'SA SSF', 'aaa'],
    'Random': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'X': ['correct', 'wrong','correct', 'correct','wrong']}
df =pd.DataFrame(data)
print "Original DataFrame:"
print df
print "="*35
x = df[~df.Classification.isin(accurate_ICB)]
print x
print "="*35
df.ix[x.index,'X'] = df['Classification']
print df
```

In pandas 0.10.1 it produces:

```
  Classification  Random        X
0  SA EQUITY CFD       1  correct
1            bbb       2      bbb
2      SA EQUITY       3  correct
3         SA SSF       4  correct
4            aaa       5      aaa
```

in pandas 0.11.0 the bottom right aaa becomes a bbb.   ANy Column between the column being checked and the one being changed seems to trigger the changed behavior

Comment: This code fragment looks fine, works in 0.11 with pretend data. Perhaps you could append a small example which exhibits this behaviour, and also post the traceback. (Also, you can convert this to use the new `loc`, but results should be equivalent.)

Comment: What are the dtypes of 'A' and 'Classification' ?

Comment: values in A and Classification both text dtypes

Comment: Slicing like that into object type is pretty suspect, wouldn't you expect alignment issues, are you sure this worked before??

Comment: Presumably the issue comes with large strings in 'Classification' and small ones in 'A' (perhaps making that extreme would give you an example?).

Comment: yes been back and forth between the two versions of pandas in with virtualenv wrapper. The last line slice is definitely the problem.   Worked in previous version ... "Wrong" result with new.    Agree that it is bit adventurous code.   tried iterating over frame before, but that did not work inside the class.

Comment: both columns are populated by relatively short strinngs (less than 20 chars).   I agree that it is rather wild slicing.   My best guess is that the older version allowed thi, but that it breaks silently on new.   Still working on getting a smaller example

Comment: :) starting to look like there could be an interesting question in here! (not to do with the new `.loc` :) )

Comment: Got small dataset that reproduce the problem.   Added it to question.   Seems to be that any column between the two columns trigger the unexpected behavior in pandas 0.11.0

Comment: Excellent work. Will have a look at this later (if you haven't got an answer already :) )

Comment: Well... it's a bug! and it's fixed in the 0.11.1 (out soon!). Thanks for finding it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3836) in 0.11, on the bright side it appears to be fixed in 0.11.1 (out very soon).

```
0.11.1.dev-bbcafd8
Original DataFrame:
  Classification  Random        X
0  SA EQUITY CFD       1  correct
1            bbb       2    wrong
2      SA EQUITY       3  correct
3         SA SSF       4  correct
4            aaa       5    wrong
===================================
  Classification  Random      X
1            bbb       2  wrong
4            aaa       5  wrong
===================================
  Classification  Random        X
0  SA EQUITY CFD       1  correct
1            bbb       2      bbb
2      SA EQUITY       3  correct
3         SA SSF       4  correct
4            aaa       5      aaa
```

Comment: On the even brighter side, I've [added your example](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/3839) to the pandas testing suite.